# OpenStreetMap distances between source and destination(s)

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I'm trying to get the distances between one source point and one or more destination points, I'm using the [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) API to accomplish this.  However, the distances being returned are way off.

```
Source coordinates:
-2.2314725 | 53.4832925

Destination
-2.2315072 | 53.483238
```

Performing the following request:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/-2.2314725,53.4832925;-2.2315072,53.483238?sources=0
```

The distance between the two points should be around 41km, but the result doesn't match at all.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Below is the output from the above request:

```
{
  "durations": [
    [
      0,
      1.3
    ]
  ],
  "destinations": [
    {
      "hint": "DBhtiw0YbYteAAAASwAAAAwAAAARAAAAQMh8QZccSEFqRAFARVYzQF4AAABLAAAADAAAABEAAABqpgAAg_Pd_0MXMANP893_HRcwAwEAXxOHnFES",
      "distance": 5.459720867300434,
      "name": "",
      "location": [
        -2.231421,
        53.483331
      ]
    },
    {
      "hint": "DBhtiw0YbYtRAAAAWAAAAAwAAAARAAAA27FaQUMzakFqRAFARVYzQFEAAABYAAAADAAAABEAAABqpgAAnPPd_zcXMAMt893_5hYwAwEAXxOHnFES",
      "distance": 11.644459328154321,
      "name": "",
      "location": [
        -2.231396,
        53.483319
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    {
      "hint": "DBhtiw0YbYteAAAASwAAAAwAAAARAAAAQMh8QZccSEFqRAFARVYzQF4AAABLAAAADAAAABEAAABqpgAAg_Pd_0MXMANP893_HRcwAwEAXxOHnFES",
      "distance": 5.459720867300434,
      "name": "",
      "location": [
        -2.231421,
        53.483331
      ]
    }
  ],
  "code": "Ok"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- <strike>You probably mixed latitude and longitude. [-2.2314725, 53.4832925](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/-2.23147/53.48329) is somewhere in the ocean whereas [53.4832925,-2.2314725](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/53.48329/-2.23147) is in Manchester.</strike> Sorry, I was wrong. OSRM expects `lon,lat`.
- The two locations are almost identical. They are only 7 meters apart.

Comment: I've reversed the lat and long in the query, but the distances seem even further apart:: 316478 metres which is about 316km.  The real distance between the two points is around 40km.  The new query I've tested is: http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/53.4832925,-2.2314725;53.483238,-2.2315072?sources=0 (Manchester and Blackburn).  Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what OSRM is doing in your query. However your [new coordinates are still right next to each other](https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_foot&route=53.4832925%2C-2.2314725%3B53.483238%2C-2.2315072). Where did you get these numbers?

Comment: Also please note that you are using the [*table* service](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/#table-service) of OSRM. This is not the regular *route* services. As far as I understand the distance is located in the `distances` array.

Comment: The coordinates have been obtained from google maps.  Also, I have tested with the route query as well: http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/-2.5064613,53.7455969;-2.2384717,53.4842935?overview=false

The result recognises one of the locations, and the destination location is off by one street - but again, the distances make no sense in the result.

Comment: I guess there is something broken with the OSRM demo server. Better try a different public instance, set up your own or switch to a different online router (for example Valhalla or GraphHopper). Your request works fine for the OSRM instance run by FOSSGIS: https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-foot/route/v1/driving/-2.5064613,53.7455969;-2.2384717,53.4842935?overview=false. [edit] Wait, now I get a reasonable distance for your URL, too (43780.9). Guess there are some hiccups?

Comment: You're right, distance seems to correct now, thanks for the alternative suggestions too, these too may help if I run into problems again.

Comment: @MusaffarPatel please I need your help, is osrm free? and can be use in php project? I need to calculate distance between customer and multiple stores, but with paid services it is very very expenseive

Comment: @FaragHalain OSRM and various other OSM-based routers are open source. However usually the public routing instances have a strict usage policy because running them costs money. You can install and run your own routing service (OSRM or any of the other OSM-based online routers).

Comment: @FaragHalain, Yes it's open source and free.  I was using it for the same purpose you are in and in a php project, however I wouldn't recommend it for production use.  The public routing servers are not as reliable as Google Maps and for this reason I switched to Google Maps (Distance Matrix API)

Comment: @MusaffarPatel I need OSRM only for showing the list of stores but when customer place the order, I will use googlematrix, you know every customer when he send his location to get the nearst stores the request will be 1 to 100 which means 100 requests for every customer, with google it is very expensive if I have 10000 customers, can you just guid me how to get the directions offline from OSRM in order to store in database then will use it in production?